# Special Price - how to display regular price without VAT (tax)?

Tags: price

I have a few products that I want to offer at a discount.

I want to use the 'special price' function, but when I do, the regular price is displayed including VAT (tax). I display all of my prices ex VAT (tax).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmpFi.jpg
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mcEo.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check : `System/Configuration/Sales/Tax/Price Display setting` try with configuration

[image]

Comment: Hi - Just checked them and they are both set to Excluding Tax

Comment: @Andy can you check under current store view also by changing to your store view as here : http://prntscr.com/hbnirf

Comment: Hi - I checked and you are correct, I hadn't drilled down that far. The problem now is that it only displays the regular price and the special price. It doesn't display what the price is with VAT. Thanks again,  Andy.